# Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch error

Tags: objective-c, ios

I keep getting this error, and I cannot figure out why. Everything was working fine, and all of the sudden I got this error. I had not changed the code, and I set the rootViewController in the delegate, so I don't see why I am getting this error. Here is the code from my appDelegate.m file.

```
#import "WhereAmIAppDelegate.h"
#import "WhereAmIViewController.h"

@implementation WhereAmIAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    WhereAmIViewController *wvc = [[WhereAmIViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"WhereAmIViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[self window]setRootViewController:wvc];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I clearly set the rootViewController, so I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening -- I dropped your code into a new project (started from the empty application template), added a new controller file WhereAmIViewController, and it all worked fine.

Comment: Try adding this line :NSLog(@"%@",self.window.rootViewController); just before the return statement and see what it logs.  Also try logging wvc and see if it returns your view controller.  Did you override the initWithNibName:bundle: method in that class?

Comment: Yeah, double check WhereAmIViewController overrides, you are getting nil in rootViewController.

Comment: It is possible if you are creating window in xib and again allocating it here. also try to use `self.window.rootViewController=wvc;`

Comment: I just made a new project and imported the files and everything worked fine. But thanks for the answers everyone.